# Axios Post request while using nextJS routing and next-i18next not to use language routing

Tags: next.js, next-i18next

I am having trouble with my axios post request:

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-i18next

and it prepends the language url to the api when sending a post request -- however I do not wish this behaviour

My axios request :

```
 const { data } = await axios.post(`api/login`, {
        email,
        password,
      });
```

results in :

localhost:3000/language/api/login

My Next config :

```
const { i18n } = require("./next-i18next.config");
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
  i18n,
};
module.exports = nextConfig;
```

next-i18next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    defaultLocale: "en",
    locales: ["en", "ua"],
    localePath: "./locales",
  },
};
```

... I want all my url request routes to go to the correct routing when the language is selected ... but I do not want my api requests to.  They can just go to the default english.

How to change this behaviour?

Thx!

Answer (score 1):

try changing

```
 const { data } = await axios.post(`api/login`, {
        email,
        password,
      });
```

to this

```
 const { data } = await axios.post(`/api/login`, {
        email,
        password,
      });
```